# Chromedriver Installation using Docker file but the chrome driver does not reflect in the mentioned directory

Tags: python-3.x, docker, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, dockerfile

**Set base image (host OS)**

```
FROM python:3.8
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
python-pip
```

**Installing wget command**

```
RUN pip install wget
```

**Copy the dependencies file to the working directory**

```
COPY requirements.txt .
```

**Install dependencies**

```
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

**Trying to install the chrome driver**

```
RUN wget -O /tmp/chromedriver.zip  https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/88.0.4324.96/chromedriver_mac64.zip
```

Answer (score 2):

Why are you using chrome driver for mac distribution in ubuntu container ? I am not sure of what's beneath it, but I guess there might be some issues due to os type.(Not sure)

You can try adding the ubuntu distribution as shown below, it should work.

```
RUN wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add - \
    sudo sh -c 'echo "deb https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list' \
    sudo apt-get -y update \
    sudo apt-get -y install google-chrome-stable

RUN sudo apt-get -y install chromium-chromedriver
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can't I use chromedriver for google chrome